# How do ASP.NET application settings in an Azure App Service work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

A [Microsoft Azure blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) from 2013 details how to use the application settings and connection strings in Azure app services. However, one part is not quite clear to me:

> For ASP.NET web applications, there is some extra runtime magic that is available as well when using the .NET 4.5 framework (note:  this magic is not available if you choose .NET 3.5 since it relies on functionality that only exists in .NET 4.5).

The author describes how you can use the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class to access the application settings and connection strings configured in the Azure portal.

How does this "extra runtime magic" work? Does the .NET Framework include Azure-specific code, or does Azure inject something, similar to how diagnostics will add a trace listener?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, are you interested by _what_ it does or _how_? Because the later one can only be answered by Azure engineers.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can edit my question to be more clear. I understand it allows me to access the Azure application settings using the regular ConfigurationManager (which is why I mentioned it in the question). I am just curious how it works.

Comment: Then the only answers we can give you will be speculations.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this "extra runtime magic" work? Does the .NET Framework include Azure-specific code, or does Azure inject something, similar to how diagnostics will add a trace listener?

As your article refered to,

> If the website’s web.config file references the same connection string in the  configuration section, then Windows Azure Web Sites will automatically update the connection string at runtime using the value shown in the portal.

Yes, Azure inject something.It is a feature of Azure App Service. For .NET apps, the application settings on portal are injected into your .NET configuration `AppSettings`/`Connection strings` at runtime, overriding existing settings.

Hope it can help you. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings).